# Swing VerticalBox elements size

Tags: java, swing

I develop my first application in Java for Windows. I need make simple form wich contains left and right panels. Left panel contains input field at the top and list bellow it. Right field contains web browser.

I placed all component on frame, but text field height it too large. I need, that it height was one or two line, all place bellow must place list.

How can I do this?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeRyU.png

Comment: What is a `VerticalBox`?  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: Look at screenshot. VerticalBox is element from category Struts & Springs

Comment: *"Look at screenshot."*   It's too small to see.  Lack of code, an unreadable screenhsot.. 'not a real question'.

Comment: Link to screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EeRyU.png

Comment: Note that a multi-line `JTextField` might confuse the user as it only accepts single-line input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should give all available space under a one-line textfied to the list

```
JPanel container = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
container.add( new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH );
container.add( new JScrollPane( list ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

Absolutely no idea how to achieve this with a drag-and-drop Swing UI designer.